# Generate script for table with data in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to generate script for a table with data in sql server 2005?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **FREE** [SQL Script Generator](http://www.sqlscriptgenerator.com/):

[image]

It can generate scripts for both the object structures, as well as the data.